# ReactJS and Spring Boot: Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: reactjs, flutter, spring-boot, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

We are developing an application where Web is in ReactJS, Mobile app is in Flutter and the backend APIs are in Spring Boot.

What would be the best design/architecture to integrate the STRIPE payment gateway in terms of security?

I went through the article below and would like to know if this is the best possible solution?
https://medium.com/sipios/adding-payments-to-your-web-application-an-introduction-to-stripe-integration-3abd7354206a

Comment: Just listen for stripe [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) and create an endpoint in your application that handles it. That's pretty much all you need. Stripe will call your webhook depending on what [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types) had occurred

Comment: One more thing to add, If you want something quick and don't mind using stripe's existing checkout api, then don't use the payment intent api, instead use the [checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works) api

Comment: @smac89 thank you. I understand the webhook part, but how will the Fontend page(say at ReactJS) will be notified once the payment notification is receveid at backend(Spring boot) via webhook? I believe the front-end has to wait till the payment is being peocessed and show SUCCESS/FAILURE message on completion.

Comment: There are a couple of ways that come to mind: The easiest one is to use the prebuilt checkout pages offered by stripe. This page will handle all aspects of the payment and you only need to listen for a couple of events in the webhook. The other option is to create an endpoint in your backend which should tell you when the payment has completed successfully. How you determine if the payment is complete is up to you, but this should be done in your backend using some data from stripe. For example using the [payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-payment-intents) api